# Interpretations of probabilities and percentages

Tags: netlogo

Thank you very much for your help for coding my model,

If you do not mind please, I want to ask you about some interpretations in the coding
I am sorry I am not expert in mathematics

```
to move
ask turtles with [gender = "male" ]
[ if ( random-float 1) <= 0.025]
```

why it is <= and what is the interpretation of this code,

and for the percentage

```
 ask turtles

  [ if random 100 <= 50
       [become-fat]]
```

the same question why <=  if we always say  50 % in the group will be fat why we put this sign???

and what is the different between random and random float

sorry for disturbance

Comment: Are you confused about why an inequality is used there at all or why it's `<=` and not `<`?

Comment: yes why I add <= instead of = or <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two primitives is that:

- [`random`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random) gives you only [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) numbers, e.g.: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.
- [`random-float`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-float) gives you [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers, e.g.: 0.0, 0.125, 0.528476587245, 3.66, etc.

Both can be used to make things happen probabilistically in NetLogo. I'll start with the use of `random`, which is slightly easier to understand.

#### Using `random`

As stated in [the documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random), if you pass a positive number to `random`, it will give you a number that is greater or equal to 0, but strictly less than that number.

For example, `random 2` will always give you either 0 or 1. You could use that to simulate the flipping of a coin:

```
ifelse random 2 = 0 [ print "heads" ] [ print "tail" ].
```

That will print `"heads"` 50% of the time (when `random 2` gives you 0), and `"tail"` 50% of the time (when `random 2` gives you 1).

Now it's easy to generalize this to probabilities expressed in percentages by using `random 100` instead of `random 2`. I'll use an example with 50%, but it could very well be 25%, 80% or even 1% or 100%.

Now since `random 100` gives you a number between 0 and 99 inclusively, it means that the first 50 numbers it can give you are: 0, 1, 2, 3... all the way to 49. And the next 50 are: 50, 51, 52, 53... all the way to 99. You can imagine a 100-sided dice labeled from 0 to 99 if you wish.

If you want your turtles to "become fat" 50% of the time, you can do:

```
ask turtles [ if random 100 < 50 [become-fat] ]
```

Notice that I used the `<` (strictly less) sign instead of the `<=` (less or equal) sign. This is because I only want the turtles to become fat if the "dice" lands on one of the first 50 faces, from 0 to 49.

(If you used `random 100 <= 50`, like in the code you posted above, they would actually have a 51% probability of becoming fat and a 49% probability to *not* become fat. You should now also be able to figure out why something like `if random 100 = 50` doesn't make sense: it would only be true if the "dice" lands exactly on 50, which happens only 1% of the time.)

If you wanted your turtles to become fat only 20% of the time, you'd want to use the first 20 faces of the dice, from 0 to 19:

```
ask turtles [ if random 100 < 20 [become-fat] ]
```

It is often enough to use `random 100` when dealing with probabilities in NetLogo.

#### Using `random-float`

Sometimes, however, you need a little more precision. And mathematically oriented work often expresses probabilities as numbers between 0.0 (for 0%) and 1.0 (for 100%). In those cases, `random-float 1` comes handy. Again, as stated [in the documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-float), `random-float` will give you a number between 0 (inclusively) and the number you pass to it (exclusively). Thus, `random-float 1` gives you a number between 0.0 and 1.0 (but never exactly 1.0).

This expression:

```
random-float 1 < 0.025
```

will be true 2.5% of the time.

The dice metaphor doesn't work for `random-float`, but you can imagine a [roulette wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette) (or a [wheel of fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_Fortune_%28U.S._game_show%29#Main_game)). Asking if `random-float 1 < 0.025` is like painting a "pie slice" that's 2.5% of the circumference of the wheel, spinning the wheel, and checking if the ball (or the arrow, or whatever) falls in that slice.

Now does it matter if you use `<=` instead of `<` with `random-float`? Not a whole lot. It would only make a difference if the wheel falls *exactly* on the line that separates your pie slice from the rest of the wheel, and the probability of that happening is very very small.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but can I ask you a stupid question :D why percentage from 1 to 99 not 100

Comment: because you consider zero???? but if i want to say 1% only it will be less than 1 only zero so it will not be 1% right?  and also i want to know if i can use random float with percentages or not

Comment: Nicolas said 0 to 99, not 1 to 99. As for `random 100 < 1`, that would in fact give a 1% chance. There are 100 possible outcomes (0 to 99) and exactly 1 of them is less than 1, so that's 1 in 100 which is 1%. `random-float 100 < 1` also gives a 1% chance.