# Creating another kind of turtles in go button according to slider percentage

Tags: probability, netlogo

I am trying to create land use model in a city. Every GO or tick x percent (according to slider) migrants (turtles) will be sprouted in random patches which there are no turtles on it.
Currently I am still using below code, it doesn't use slider but specific number 1000 > 9 which is close to 2% according to number of turtles I created in setup.

to go

```
 ask patches with [pcolor = green and any? turtles-here = false] 
    [ if random 1000 < 9 [sprout-migrants 1 [
    set color red
    set shape "default"
    set size 1
    set-income
    find-residence]]]
tick
end
```

Comment: Is your problem in creating a slider or using probability in percentages? If later see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898582/interpretations-of-probabilities-and-percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a slider named `x` that you want to control the percent change, then replace:

```
random 1000 < 9
```

with

```
random 100 < x
```

If the slider can take on non-integer values, then do

```
random-float 100 < x
```

Comment: if we use random 1000 < 9 does it mean that there is 9/1000 possibility random number < 9 show up?

Answer (score 0):

you could also use this code. this way you don't need to run the if-statement to all of the patch.

assuming the slider is `x` as percent and turtle-numbers is contain the number of turtles you setup

```
let migrants-to-sprout ((x / 100) * turtle-numbers)
```

you set the number of turtles you want to sprout first and then make it as the loop indicator

```
repeat migrants-to-sprout [

  ask patches with [pcolor = green and not any? turtles-here]
  [
     sprout-migrants 1 [...]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @M.R Murazza, I've just tried it but it's error. It's said that "FOREACH expected input to be a list but got the number 193.62 instead.error while observer running FOREACH
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'"
this is the code I use    




`to go 
   let pendatang-to-sprout ((2 / 100) * count turtles)
    foreach pendatang-to-sprout 
    [ask patches with [pcolor = green and any? turtles-here = false][sprout-pendatangs 1[
set color red
set shape "default"
set size 1
set-income
    find-residence]]]
tick
end`

Comment: I think M.R. meant `repeat` not `foreach`?

Comment: ah yes, I did mean `repeat`. Sorry. I will edit it right away.

Comment: just to be sure so that the code will work. you might want to `round` or `floor` the number of `pendatang-to-sprout`, depends on wether you want to round it up or down. since it can contain decimal number and I think repeat only work on integer.

so it will go like this `set pendatang-to-sprout (round pendatang-to-sprout)` if you want to round it.
otherwise it goes like this `set pendatang-to-sprout (floor pendatang-to-sprout)`. and put it before the repeat